# Using a length attribute and a start coordinate to get the end coordinate on a vector in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a road network (with vectors all in correct direction of travel). 
I  have a number of coordinate pairs (call these the start lat longs) that are found on the network. 
Each start lat long has an assigned Lenght attribute (ranging from 2m - 300m),
What I'm having trouble with is locating an end lat long coordinate pair (on the network) using the Length attribute. 
I know how to get the length to point and extract coordinates, but is there someway in fme to combine the Length to point transformer and add the Length attribute to then be able to extract the end lat longs?

Comment: To get an ending lat/long, you will also need an azimuth in addition to length.

Comment: If i have the vector already and just need to travel past my start lat long coordinate by a Length from a seperate attribute would i need the azimuth?

Comment: So you basically have an incomplete or short vector that points to where the ending should be?

Comment: I have a vector that is say 1000m long (ordered in direction of travel). My start lat long is found 200m along that vector.  My start lat long has an attribute of 112m as a Length. What i need is the coordinate pair that is found 312m along the vector in the direction of travel.

Comment: I have over 10,000 start lat longs each with differing lenght measures..

Comment: Can you have another go at describing the problem, including what you've already tried? Just click edit below the question to update it. There is too much information hidden in the comments, and not all of them will show once there are a few. Also, you don't need to add the thanks / name on the question.

Comment: Is it possible that the road will turn within that length attribute?  Or is it always a straight distance?  For example, say you have a road that is 1000m.  And your starting point is 250m and your length is 500m so your end point is 750m along the road.  However, what if there is a turn at the midpoint?  You still need the end point on the road, and a straight line wouldn't work. I may have a solution for you but I need a bit more information.

Comment: Maybe Snipper and CoordinateExtractor would be a good starting point?

Answer (score 2):

If you have one of the newer versions of FME, there are two online transformers that should do the trick:

[image: fme workbench]

`AzimuthCalculator` and `2DDirectionExtender` seems like what you're looking for. I just typed the names of the transformers directly into the Workbench screen and they showed up.

Combine this with the `CoordinateExtractor` to find the ending coordinate.

Comment: The step i'm missing is before this. I have a length measure and the start lat long along the vector. I need to be able to combine the length to point transformer and then add my length attribute to then use this coordinate extractor..

Comment: Edited my answer with some online transformers you could use.